# How to create a raw image file with content inside to emulate an SD card for Android

Tags: android

I'm working on app which will read folders and files from an SD card, now to need to create a raw image file which will emulate the SD card, but when I use `mksdcard` it only creates an empty raew image file.

Answer (score 0):

```
void saveImage() {
        File filename;
        try {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

            new File(path + "/folder/subfolder").mkdirs();
            filename = new File(path + "/folder/subfolder/image.jpg");

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

            bitMapImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), filename.getAbsolutePath(), filename.getName(), filename.getName());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File is Saved in  " + filename, 1000).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```